# PHP - Removing characters from string doesn't change strlen()

Tags: php, string, session

I'm in the process of coding a cart for a webstore. Right now, I'm trying add a "Remove from Cart" Button.

The way I have it set up is that `$_SESSION['id']` contains all the product-IDs the customer added to the cart, which are then looped through to create a table with 5 columns: img | name | size | price | "Remove from Cart"-Button.

**My goal is that upon clicking the button, the product is simply removed from `$_SESSION['id']`. As there is now one less item in the variable, the `strlen($_SESSION['id'])` should in turn also be lowered by one.**

Every button has a unique name thanks to the for loop adding the current iteration to the its name: `<td valign="middle"><form action="#" method="post"><input type="submit" name=" delete_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="Remove"></form></td>`.

To check if one of those buttons was pressed, I incorporated another for-loop:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($_SESSION['id']); $i++) { 
        if (isset($_POST['delete_'.$i])) {
            $_SESSION['id'][$i]=""; //removes item from $_SESSION['id']. Instead of "" I also tried NULL
            $_SESSION['size'][$i]=false; //removes corresponding size.
            //I may be mistaken, but PRG should be implemented to avoid problems with the form being resent upon refreshing the page
            header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Once the button was clicked, the item is indeed removed from the `$_SESSION['id']` string, but weirdly enough the string length stays the same.

Having performed a `var_dump ($_SESSION['id']);` after adding and removing 3 items from the cart, the result is: `string(3) ""`. So, the string has a length of 3 but contains nothing? How can that be?

This is obviously bound to create some challenges! As the table rows are created based on the `strlen($_SESSION['id'])`, I am left with 3 (or however many products I removed from cart) rows full of error messages telling me about an "Undefined Index". It does not say "Uninitialized string offset" though, so this to me implies that the offset existed, but there was simply nothing there to work with.

Any help would be strongly appreaciated!
Felix

Comment: Why do you need to store the `size`? Save added to cart items in the session as an array of item ids `$_SESSION['id'][$item_id] = $item_id`. When removing the item from the cart use `unset($_SESSION['id'][$item_id])`. When displaying cart items use the loop `foreach ($_SESSION['id'] as $item_id)`.

Comment: Thank you for your input!! Having redone everything using arrays, I implemented the structure as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to change the length of a string. When you assign an empty string to a string character, it doesn't shift all the other characters over, it treats it as putting a character with code `0` in that position. You can see it with this code:

```
$str = "abcdef";
$str[1] = "";
echo $str; //acdef
echo ord($str[1]); // 0
```

So it's equivalent to:

```
$str[1] = chr(0);
```

Conversely, if you try to assign more than one character, it just assigns the first character:

```
$str[1] = "xyz";
```

acts like:

```
$str[1] = "x";
```

Don't try to use a string as an array, that's not what it's intended for. Use a real array, then you can use `unset($_SESSION['id'][$i])`;

Comment: You're the man!
Me using a string instead of an array was nothing more than a stupid relict from a botch I performed when I first started! I redid everything using a multi-dimensional array `$_SESSION['products']=["product ID", "size"]` so I can now easily remove entries from the cart! To prevent the for-loop from giving me errors, the array is sorted every time a product is removed.